# copy arr1 to arr 2 at given index n and arr 1 and arr2 should be same after function runs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to copy arr1 to arr 2 at given index n and arr 1 and arr2 should be same after function runs. So I have put a = arr2 and operate on a but arr2 is also changing

```js
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
    let a = arr2
    console.log(a)
    a.splice(n,0,...arr1);
    console.log(arr2)
    return a
      
  }
  console.log(frankenSplice([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in javascript are mutable, so when you use

```
let a = arr2
```

array `a` becomes `arr2`, and when you modify one, you modify both (beacuse they are essentialy the same array)

To solve your problem, you can use spread operator to copy content of your original array to the new one, so it would look like this

```
let a = [...arr2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `a` a copy of `arr2`, one way to do that would be to use **[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)**:

```js
const frankenSplice = (arr1, arr2, n) => {
  const a = arr2.slice(0); // 0 is not required but makes it slightly faster
  a.splice(n, 0, ...arr1);
  return a
}

const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = [4, 5, 6];
console.log(frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, 1));
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `flatMap` should make simplify for this case.

```js
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
  return arr2.flatMap((num, i) => (i === n ? [...arr1, num] : num));
}
console.log(frankenSplice([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 1));
```